# Asymptote takes too long to render images

Tags: 3d, asymptote

I need to include several 3d graphics in a LaTeX document, and decided to use asymptote. However, it seems that rendering takes too long. A document with 20 images takes more than 15 minutes to finish compiling.

I wonder if there is a way to tall asymptote to only draw the mesh (I suppose that would be quicker) and switch to a nicer rendering when I compile a final version of the document.

I have been compiling the document with these commands:

```
pdflatex text.tex
asy text-*.asy
pdflatex text.tex
```

As an example, the following takes a long time to finish, even though I have only told asymptote to just draw the mesh.

```
import graph3;
import contour3;
settings.render=4;

real f(real x, real y, real z) {return (x/2)^2 + y- (z/2)^2;}

draw(surface(contour3(f,(-3,-3,-3),(3,3,3),32)),surfacepen=nullpen,meshpen=black,render(compression=Low,merge=true));

defaultrender.merge=true;
defaultrender.tessellate=true;
```

I'd appreciate any ideas that will make asymptote run faster, but still give a minimally reasonable result (I only need to check if the surfaces are correct, if I need to change the camera, etc).

Comment: In this circumstances the mesh takes more time, than the surface -
compare with `surfacepen=black,meshpen=nullpen`. To speed-up compilation in the draft mode
you can also reduce the number of mesh lines from `32` to, say, `4` and set `settings.render=1`, this greatly reduces the compilation time.

Comment: Thank you!!! It now compiles instantly! 8-)  Would you mind posting your comment as answer?

Comment: Another comment: If you use latexmk with the appropriate configuration as described in the Asymptote manual, only the images that have changed will be recompiled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this circumstances the mesh takes more time, than the surface - compare with `surfacepen=black,meshpen=nullpen`. To speed-up compilation in the draft mode you can also reduce the number of mesh lines from `32` to, say, `4` and set `settings.render=1`, this greatly reduces the compilation time.